# Issue with Synaptic Package Manager cos of disco and bionic retro. It seems I may be tried to install Wine too

Tags: screenshot

I have an issue with Synaptic Package Manager because of disco and bionic retros. It seems I may be tried to install Wine too.

The error says that "Error: Opening the cache (E:Malformed entry  64 in lsi file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component), E: The list of sources could nto be read.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any repositories to your machine? If so, I would remove any additional entries in /etc/apt/sources.list or sources.d/ then run

```
sudo apt auto-clean;
sudo apt update ;
sudo apt full-upgrade;
```

Comment: In your source list, copy the last 5-10 lines